# Creating a record with EmberData when testing with Jasmine

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am working on converting a Backbone application into an Ember application using Ember Data.  It works fine in the browser but the Jasmine test cases will not pass.  When I try to create a record in the Jasmine test case I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'type._create({ store: this })') in http://localhost:8888/spec/javascripts/generated/assets/application.js (line 26874)
```

This is the actual code that the error message points to:

```
createRecord: function(type, properties, transaction) {
    properties = properties || {};

    // Create a new instance of the model `type` and put it
    // into the specified `transaction`. If no transaction is
    // specified, the default transaction will be used.
    //
    // NOTE: A `transaction` is specified when the
    // `transaction.createRecord` API is used.
    var record = type._create({
      store: this // line 26874
    });
```

The actual code that the test case is executing looks like this:

```
nutrient = App.Nutrient.createRecord({"name_min":"nut 1","female_31_50_min":7.5,"male_31_50_min":8.0,"created_at":"2011-10-10T01:31:53Z","female_51_70_min":8.5,"updated_at":"2011-10-12T12:28:35Z","male_70_plus_min":10.0,"female_19_30_min":6.5,"child_4_8_min":4.0,"male_19_30_min":7.0,"lactating_14_18_min":5.75,"infant_0_05_min":1.0,"female_70_plus_min":9.5,"pregnant_14_18_min":5.8,"infant_6_12_min":2.0,"id":1,"male_9_13_min":5.0,"child_1_3_min":3.0,"female_9_13_min":4.5,"female_14_18_min":5.5,"male_14_18_min":6.0,"lactating_31_50_min":7.75,"pregnant_31_50_min":7.8,"pregnant_19_30_min":6.8,"male_51_70_min":9.0,"lactating_19_30_min":6.75,"female_31_50_max":8.5,"male_31_50_max":9.0,"female_51_70_max":9.5,"male_70_plus_max":11.0,"female_19_30_max":7.5,"child_4_8_max":5.0,"male_19_30_max":8.0,"lactating_14_18_max":6.75,"infant_0_05_max":2.0,"female_70_plus_max":10.5,"pregnant_14_18_max":6.8,"infant_6_12_max":3.0,"male_9_13_max":6.0,"child_1_3_max":4.0,"female_9_13_max":5.5,"female_14_18_max":6.5,"male_14_18_max":7.0,"lactating_31_50_max":8.75,"pregnant_31_50_max":9.8,"pregnant_19_30_max":7.8,"male_51_70_max":10.0,"lactating_19_30_max":7.75})

person = new App.Person.createRecord({age: 0.25})

expect(nutrient.requiredNutrientForPerson(person)).toEqual({min_amount: 1.0, max_amount: 2.0})
```

Any ideas would be appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, My Bad.  The problem is with this line:

```
person = new App.Person.createRecord({age: 0.25})
```

I needed to remove the `new` keyword and it worked correctly

Comment: Ah, didn't notice that, but it does make sense now given the error. Hope I didn't confuse matters with mention of the run loop. It's good to see some people using ember-data now - I'll have to take another look soon.

Answer (score 2):

In general, if you're having problems with a test that you don't experience in the browser, it's because the tests are running outside of the Ember run loop.

Try calling `Ember.run.sync()` before `expect()` to force synchronization. Alternatively, place any code that involves binding in an anonymous fn inside: `Ember.run(function() { })`.

Check out the ember and ember-data source for other testing examples, since coverage is pretty solid.

With that said, I'm not an ember-data expert, so I'm not sure if this is the problem you're experiencing.